# JPanel: both implementing my own paintComponent() and rendering children doesn't work

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent

I'm extending a JPanel to display a game board, and adding a JEditorPane at the bottom to hold some status text.  Unfortunately, the game board renders just fine, but the JEditorPane is just a blank gray area until I highlight the text in it, when it will render whatever text is highlighted (but not the rest).  If I'm understanding Swing right, it should work, because super.paintComponent(g) should render the other children (i.e., the JEditorPane).  Tell me, o great stackoverflow, what bonehead mistake am I making?

```
public GameMap extends JPanel {
  public GameMap() {
    JEditorPane statusLines = new JEditorPane("text/plain","Stuff");
    this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this,BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
    this.add(new Box.Filler(/*enough room to draw my game board*/));
    this.add(statusLines);
  }
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    for ( all rows ){
      for (all columns){
        //paint one tile
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Works okay for me. What JDK and L&F are you using?

Comment: Aha!  I'm a pillock! (Pillock is such an entertaining word.)  Each tile of the board has its own paint method, and the problem was that I was translating the Graphics object so that each tile can just paint from (0,0) as the upper-left corner.  And, silly me, I forgot to translate back to the global origin before painting the rest of the components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see anything immediately boneheaded about your code in general, but I would say that your component hierarchy seems a bit boneheaded.

Is there a reason why you aren't separating your objects out better?  In order to keep your code maintainable and testable, I'd encourage you to extract `GameBoard` logic into a different class.  This would give you the ability to do simplify your `GameMap` by removing the `paintComponent(...)`

```
public class GameMap extends JPanel{
  private JEditorPane status;
  private GameBoard board;
  public GameMap() {
    status= createStatusTextPane();
    board = new GameBoard();
    this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this,BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
    this.add(board);
    this.add(status);
  }
  //...all of the other stuff in the class
  // note that you don't have to do anything special for painting in this class
}
```

And then your `GameBoard` might look like

```
public class GameBoard extends JPanel {
  //...all of the other stuff in the class
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    for (int row = 0; row < numrows; row++)
      for (int column = 0; column < numcolumns ; column ++)
        paintCell(g, row, column);
  }
}
```

Comment: As I was running through solutions, I found that your method worked just fine to solve it, and did indeed separate out the code better.  See my comment on the question about a) the not-actually-mentioned-in-the-question *real* problem, and b) my being a pillock.